# How do I capture match-groups of alternation of a regular expression with split?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string

```
my $foo = 'one#two#three!four#five#six';
```

from which I want to extract the parts that are seperated by either a `#` or a `!`. This is easy enough with `split`:

```
my @parts = split /#|!/, $foo;
```

An additional requirement is that I also need to capture the exclamation marks. So I tried

```
my @parts = split /#|(!)/, $foo;
```

This however returns either an `undef` value or the exclamation mark (which is also clearly stated in the specification of split).

So, I weed out the unwanted `undef` values with `grep`:

```
my @parts = grep { defined } split /#|(!)/, $foo;
```

This does what I want.

Yet I was wondering if I can change the regular expression in a way so that I don't have to also invoke `grep`.

Comment: I'd suggest that _keeping_ the `grep` is no bad thing - it makes it much more obvious what your code is doing. E.g. `my @parts = grep { not /^#$/ } split /(#|!)/, $foo;`

Comment: +++ @Sobrique :) For reading my own code after a half year, helps if it isn't obfuscated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `split`, you may not omit the empty captures once a match is found (as there are always as many captures in the match as there are defined in the regular expression). You may use a *matching* approach here, though:

```
my @parts = $foo =~ /[^!#]+|!/g;
```

This way, you will match 1 or more chars other than `!` and `#` (with `[^!#]+` alternative), or an exclamation mark, multiple times (`/g`).

Answer (score 2):

Use "empty string followed by an exclamation mark or empty string preceded by an exclamation mark" in place of your second alternative:

```
my @parts = split /#|(?=!)|(?<=!)/, $foo;
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/6pA1wx

Comment: Rather `/#|(?=!)|(?<=!)/` if I understand the question correctly, no?

Comment: @Dada: yes, you're right. Misunderstood the question initially. Updated the answer.